# at least twenty of them

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if the following sentence is grammatically correct?

> The house was full of cats, at least twenty of them.

If yes, does it sound natural to native speakers? Or is "The house was full of cats, at least twenty" more natural (where "of them" has been omitted)?

Comment: Parentheticals (here, adding detail) have degrees of freedom not open to matrix sentences.  This sounds idiomatic, perhaps a deleted form of 'The house was full of cats, there being at least twenty of them.' Note that 'The house was full of cats. At least twenty of them were white' is unquestionably grammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions sound natural to me. (I'm a native AmE speaker.)

And yes, both versions are grammatical. "At least twenty [[of them]]" could be considered to be in apposition to "cats". It could also be considered a parenthetical expression.

Comment: I agree, but would prefer the version that adds "of them" to signal an afterthought.   If you don't add the extra words, it sounds like the number has some precision that is important, as opposed to emphasizing the shocking amount.  You could also say: "The house was full of as many as twenty cats."

Comment: An appositive NP is one that when substituted for the matrix NP in a declarative clause yields an entailment of the original. But "The house was full of at least twenty of them" is hardly an entailment of the original, thus ruling out "at least twenty of them" as an appositive NP. I agree with your second suggestion that it's a kind of parenthetical NP, i.e. a supplement, but not an appositional one.